# where can I find KeyGenParameterSpec.java

Tags: android, keystore, key-generator

I am creating a RSA key pair in my Android KeyStore. I am using eclipse.
I need to use KeyGenParameterSpec class to give my key an alias, so that I can delete it later, but I cant find this class. Can anyone let me know which jar would this be present in.
The [official page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/keystore/KeyGenParameterSpec.html) says that its present at `android.security.keystore.KeyGenParameterSpec`, but the problem is that I cant find this jar.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`KeyGenParameterSpec` is in the package `android.security.keystore`, but you can't see the constructor because it is annotate with `@hide` as you can see in the [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/keystore/java/android/security/keystore/KeyGenParameterSpec.java#253).

Quoting form the doclava [documentation](https://code.google.com/p/doclava/wiki/JavadocTags#@hide):

> When applied to a package, class, method or field, @hide removes that
>   node and all of its children from the documentation.

If you want to create a `KeyGenParameterSpec` you need to use the Builder:

```
new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(KEY_NAME, KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
        .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC)
        .setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)
        .setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds(AUTHENTICATION_DURATION_SECONDS)
        .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7)
        .build()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the problem I am facing is that which jar will have this class? As in how do I use this in my eclipse project. Where can I find the jar which contains the android.security.keystore package

Comment: It is part of the Android framework. You don't need to add any particular jar. Please note that `KeyGenParameterSpec` is added in API level 23, so if you target a different version you can't see this class.

Comment: Got it, but I also tried using KeyPairGeneratorSpec, which is supported by the older libraries. In eclipse how do I access this framework then? How do I import this class?

Comment: It is also part of the Android framework. `KeyPairGeneratorSpec` is added is API level 18. Check that your target is at least 18.

Comment: I get that, the thing is I am not creating an android project in eclipse, so cant specify a target version. I am working on a normal java project where I need to use this class. therefore the question is how can I access this class

Comment: Download the `SDK Platform` from `Android SDK Manager`, then you can find the jar here `android-sdk-macosx/platforms/android-23/android.jar`.

Comment: So, is your issue solved? If the answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark.

Comment: I ended up using android studio to get this done, but I am sure that with this jar it would have worked. So thanks for the help

Comment: @MattiaMaestrini this is my question https://stackoverflow.com/q/66760328/11630822 getting exception for my key alias in KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder.. if you have any idea about it, then please answer there.