# androidx_security_crypto_encrypted_prefs_key_keyset does not exist

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, obfuscation

I am trying to edit a user's set of shared preferences in a more secure way using `EncryptedSharedPreferences`

```
private fun provideSecureSharedPreference(context: Context): SharedPreferences {
    val masterKey = MasterKey.Builder(context).setKeyScheme(MasterKey.KeyScheme.AES256_GCM).build()
    return EncryptedSharedPreferences.create(
        context, "secret_shared_prefs", masterKey, EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefKeyEncryptionScheme.AES256_SIV,
        EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefValueEncryptionScheme.AES256_GCM
    )
}
```

It runs fine when I use `minifyEnabled false`
Now I'm trying to Obfuscate the code by doing `minifyEnabled true`

To avoid other error, for now I have put just these lines in my `proguard-rules.pro` file

```
-dontobfuscate
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*,!code/allocation/variable
```

but the probelem is when I set `minifyEnable true` I am getting

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: can't read keyset; the pref value __androidx_security_crypto_encrypted_prefs_key_keyset__ does not exist
```

I try to search old post from Stackoverflow and other channels but could not find the solution. Looking for a help thanks.

Comment: did you find the solution?

Comment: any solution on this?

Comment: meanwhile did someone find the solution?

Answer (score 3):

I managed to get rid of this message:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: can't read keyset; the pref value **androidx_security_crypto_encrypted_prefs_key_keyset** does not exist

by using the [1.1.0-alpha06](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/security#1.1.0-alpha06) version, where it says:

> Updated Tink dependency to 1.8.0

So, add this to your app `build.gradle`:

```
implementation "androidx.security:security-crypto:1.1.0-alpha06"
```

Another option would be to use the the crypto stable [1.0.0](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/security#version_100_3) version and Tink 1.8.0 version, until `security-crypto:1.1.0` is released:

```
implementation "androidx.security:security-crypto:1.0.0"
implementation "com.google.crypto.tink:tink-android:1.8.0"
```